# Dynamic table of thumbnails/urls from YouTube API with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, api, youtube, fancybox

I'm very new to js and jQuery, pardon my bad code.  Trying to dynamically generate a formatted table of YouTube thumbnails/urls from a keyword query.  Thumbnails need to be wrapped in an  tag with fancybox class settings to trigger a fancybox player.  I'm setting all the necessary 'a' and 'img' tags as vars and just trying to parse the JSON feed for video IDs, plug those into the url and thumbnail templates and then generate a table that starts a new row of thumbs after every 9 cells.

Here's my code.  Right now it only generates a single column and keeps repeating the same IDs and adding a new one every iteration.  Any help is hugely appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var vidCell1 = '<a class="fancybox-media" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=';
    var vidCell2 = '"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/';
    var vidCell3 = '/hqdefault.jpg" width="100" alt="" /></a>';
    var mytablebody = '<tbody><tr>';
    var ti;
    var id;

    $.getJSON("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=mirthkon&v=2&alt=jsonc",function(youtubeJSON) {

        ti = youtubeJSON.data.totalItems;    
        for (var i=0; i<=ti; i++) {            
            id = youtubeJSON.data.items[i].id;
            mytablebody += "<td>" + vidCell1 + id + vidCell2 + id + vidCell3 + "</td>";
            mytablebody += "</tr></tbody>";
            $('.thumbs').append(mytablebody);
        };    
    });​
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="thumbs" width="100" height="100" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>​
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tmpl = '<a class="fancybox-media" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={{id}}"><img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/{{id}}/hqdefault.jpg" width="100" alt="" /></a>';
jQuery.getJSON("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=mirthkon&v=2&alt=jsonc",function(json) {
   jQuery.each(json.data.items, function(i, item){
       jQuery(document.body).append(tmpl.replace(/{{id}}/g, item.id));
   });
});
```

This is fast and dirty and I made it right on this stackoverflow page using Chrome inspector. It just appends all created youtube links to the document. To optimize you should create a div before the loop, append all links to it in the loop, then after the loop append that one div to the DOM. Also, while testing this it looks like Youtube throttles API calls, so you might one to cache this in localStorage or something so you don't make a lot of calls to youtube each time the page is accessed.

Two additional comments: I created a template string for you so you don't have to build out a long string each time. When writing and testing scripts `console.log` is your friend. `console.log(youtubeJSON)` for example to see what the data looks like. You can also do this  for functions you don't understand what data is passing to you inside of them. Inside the `jQuery.each` you can put `console.log('args', arguments)` to log what the method is passing to you each time.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate thru the results which you are not doing and thats why you are getting the same id over and over.

```
$.getJSON("//URL", function(json) {
     $.each(json, function(key, val) {
         render(val);
     });
 })
```

Here's an example of how to do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyspouken/XLWUC/

Comment: I've tried the each function, but am unclear on what parameters to set to pull the ids in the (key, val) function.  my current code pulls an id with json.data.items[0].id (for the first id of many).  How can I iterate thru all of the json's ids and set each to my id var to append to my table?  Thanks!!

Comment: Interesting.  I get the gist of what you did there, but where you lost me is in your append statement.  I don't get what you're doing here:

    append($('<li />').html($('<img />')

But I now see how you're pulling each id and setting it to a var.  THANKS!

Comment: It's a jQuery method that lets you append html elements. http://api.jquery.com/append/ there are also other methods that will work for you when generating dynamic content. For a complete list look here http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'm still wrapping my brain around it all, but I'm starting to grasp it.  I've only been writing javascript and jQuery code for a week or so.  I've bit off more than I can chew! :)